# Set IPv6 for adapter on Windows with C

Tags: c++, winapi, networking, ipv6

I want to add/set an IPv6 address on an existing interface using C/C++ code through Windows API (iphlpapi). I don't want to use netsh or powershell cmdlets, but something more native.

Until now, I have tried with `CreateUnicastIpAddressEntry` and I want to know if there's something persistent and complete to set other IPv6 values like gateway or DNS.

Isn't there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: The [`CreateUnicastIpAddressEntry` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814401.aspx) says: "*To create an IPv4 address that persists, the [EnableStatic method of the Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390383.aspx) in the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) controls may be used.*"  It does not mention IPv6 persistence, though.

Comment: Yes, I need something that works with v6 and also to be persistent. Maybe a good idea is trying with WMI calls through `MSFT_NetIPAddress.Create`.